# How can I set HTTP Post entity like Java's method HttpPost.setEntity

Tags: go

I'm a new golang programmer. In java it's very easy to set with method HTTP.setEntity(). but in golang, I have test servel way to set it, but our server still missing receive entity data.
Here is code:

```
func bathPostDefects(){
    url := "http://127.0.0.1/edit"
    var jsonStr =  []byte(`{"key":"abc","id":"110175653","resolve":2,"online_time":"2016-7-22","priority":1,"comment":"something.."}`)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST",url,bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    fmt.Println("ContentLength: ",len(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type","application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Length",string(len(jsonStr)))
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp,err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
}
```

problem find it, it is cause by our servlet has read the form values, not the request body, code update following:

```
func bathPostDefects(){
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("key", "abc")
    v.Add("id", "110175653")
    v.Add("resolve", "2")
    v.Add("online_time", "2016-7-22")
    v.Add("priority", "1")
    v.Add("comment", "something..")
    fmt.Println(v.Get("id"))
    fmt.Println(v.Get("comment"))
    resp, err := http.PostForm("http://127.0.0.1/edit",v)
    if err != nil {
          panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
}
```

thank you all you guys.

Comment: It works for me. I was able to run https://play.golang.org/p/cQmGVyelZu locally (note Playground disables the HTTP) and obtain https://requestb.in/176m02c1?inspect

Comment: Carletti, thanks for your answer, the problem is found out, because our server is read the form values not the request body. thanks a lot for your help.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a bit code to use `NewBufferString`, and tested it together with server that prints request's body:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func bathPostDefects() {
    url := "http://127.0.0.1:4141/"
    var jsonStr = `{"key":"abc","id":"110175653","resolve":2,"online_time":"2016-7-22","priority":1,"comment":"something.."}`
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBufferString(jsonStr))
    fmt.Println("ContentLength: ", len(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Length", string(len(jsonStr)))
    client := &http.Client{}
    _, err = client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func server() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        fmt.Println("Body: ", string(body))
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":4141", nil))
}
func main() {
    go server()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    bathPostDefects()
}
```

Comment: Hey! @plutov,thanks I sloved this problem. thank u for your replay.